# Dell laptop intermittently does not detect AC power charger

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, dell-xps

I have Dell XPS 13 9360 laptop that intermittently does not detect the power charger.

I tried running test on BIOS, and they say it does not detect power charger. And just now when I plugged it in, it detects the power charger, but I know this is only temporary. In other words, it is intermittent and the the problem can become permanent.

I called Dell and they say it is a hardware issue. They say I must pay for the diagnostic test. And then if I decide to get it fixed I must ship my laptop to them.

Is there anything I can do short of paying for repair, paying to extend warranty, or buying another laptop?

I am trying to Google for common solution to laptop that does not detect power charger and not finding anything.

Comment: How long have you had this laptop? Has anything close to this issue shown up anytime in the past? Also, do you have any way of testing this out with another AC power adapter. If it is a physical problem it could either be the cable that connects to the laptops receptacle port or the receptacle itself. If it is the the power adapter itself, that is good news since you can just buy a new one. But if there is an issue with the power receptacle itself, that would necessitate someone opening up the laptop to repair — or replace — the port.

Comment: My experience has been that connectors fail.  So I tend to agree with Dell and leave to you whether it is worth it or not.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I had this laptop for 3 years and it is first time issue occurred. I tested thsi on other power outlets, same results. I have another Dell laptop for 7 years and no such problem occurs.

Comment: @Marium Well, I am not asking about power outlets but using another AC power adapter. The part that connects to the laptop might be losing connection.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I don't have another AC power adapter.

Comment: My only suggestion is to buy another power adapter that is compatible with the Dell XPS 13 9360 and see if that works. But it most likely is the port inside the laptop and (if so) a professional needs to repair that.

Comment: Dell power bricks have a chip in them that the bios reads, evidently it is going bad, replace the charger will a Dell branded one.

Comment: @Moab I just ordered a new charger in case of more funny business